# How does spring Dispatcher Servlet create default beans without any XML configuration?

Tags: spring, servlets, javabeans, default, dispatcher

How does Spring Dispatcher Servlet create Default beans without any predefined XML configuration file. (I am not talking of annotations).

If we don't give any default:

1) Handler mapping object
2) Multipart Resolver
3) Theme Resolver etc...
in the XML configuration file, Spring automatically creates these beans.

How does Spring create these beans when there is no explicit declaration of these beans anywhere?
And once created are these default beans available in the Application Context? I mean can we get these beans with a call to getBean() method on the context object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`DispatcherServlet.initStrategies()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#DispatcherServlet.initStrategies%28org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext%29):

```
protected void initStrategies(ApplicationContext context) {
    initMultipartResolver(context);
    initLocaleResolver(context);
    initThemeResolver(context);
    initHandlerMappings(context);
    initHandlerAdapters(context);
    initHandlerExceptionResolvers(context);
    initRequestToViewNameTranslator(context);
    initViewResolvers(context);
}
```

You'll note that `DispatcherServlet` tries to find existing beans with some fixed name and either uses default or nothing if non found.

> 1) Handler mapping object

No resolver is used if no other resolver is configured.

> 2) Multipart Resolver

Check out [`AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java#AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse%28org.w3c.dom.Element%2Corg.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ParserContext%29) - quite complex, be warned.

> 3) Theme Resolver

`FixedThemeResolver` is used if no other resolver is configured.

The internals of Spring MVC context startup are too complex for a reason - you should not mess around with them. Just supply callbacks or beans you want to replace.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. But i can see that there is a call HandlerMapping hm = context.getBean(HANDLER_MAPPING_BEAN_NAME, HandlerMapping.class) for default handler if we have not specified any handler. getBean() method does not create a bean it just fetches the already created bean refernece from the applicaion context,where all the beans are created during context startup time. How does spring know that which default handler has to be be created and registered into the context?

Comment: @SumitTrehan: see my update. I am not sure about the second part of your question, sorry.

Comment: Thnaks for the update. Can You tell me a book/link which gives the details Spring MVC context startup?

Comment: @SumitTrehan: I don't think there are any *hard* resources as the internal are constantly *in flux*. There are some Spring MVC developers in here, maybe they can help you further?

Answer (score 0):

The default objects are added to the context when the mentioned "init" methods are called. For example, in `private void initHandlerMappings(ApplicationContext context)`, the default handler mappings are obtained by calling `getDefaultStrategies(context, HandlerMapping.class)`. Here, the following happens:

1. A `String[]` is populated with the default classnames using the `DispatcherServlet.properties`
2. Create a `Class` instance of each.
3. But to actually instantiate the default object, it calls the following method, passing in the class instance:

   ```
    protected Object createDefaultStrategy(ApplicationContext context, Class<?> clazz) {
        return context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(clazz);
   ```

   }

It is here that the default objects are fully initialized as beans.